# AngularJS access scope parameterized values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form with parameterized names like

```
 <div id="form-group">
  <label>City</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="localityGoogle" disabled="true" ng-model="localityGoogle"></input></td>
</div>

<div id="form-group">
  <label>State</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1Google" disabled="true" ng-model="administrative_area_level_1Google "></input></td>
</div>
```

In another function I obtain the values to set in the form. I iterate the structure I obtain to set the values

```
for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
   var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

   if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      addressTypeGoogle = addressType+'Google';
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      $scope.addressTypeGoogle = val;
   }
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to access the values in the scope in a way like this

```
$scope[addressTypeGoogle] = newValue;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope` is just another JS object. So anything you can do with a regular JS object you can do with scope.

```
$scope.foo = 'bar';

console.log($scope['foo']); //bar

var propName = 'foo';

console.log($scope[propName]); //bar
```

All of those are valid.